# ld: framework not found FBAudienceNetwork

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have searched for many solutions but none of them works in my case.

I am using FBAudienceNetwork in my Unity project and I want to build an iOS version. But when I build in iOS, the error message comes out.

```
ld: framework not found FBAudienceNetwork
```

What I have tried:

1. Remove FBAudienceNetwork from "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and add it again.
2. Check if FBAudienceNetwork framework name in left panel is in black.
3. Drag the folder to "Framework Search Paths" in "Build Settings".
4. Set the path in "Framework Search Paths" as "recursive".
   [image]
5. Add FBAudienceNetwork framework into "Embedded Binaries".

As this framework is not install by Podfile, I have tried to remove the framework and use cocoa pod to re-install it. But the version number is a little bit older (default version is 5.1.0, and the version cocoa pod install is 4.99.3) it comes out another error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I have already added '-lxml2' to 'Other Linker Flags' in Build Settings page according to the instruction from Facebook Developer document. And the framework should support arm64.

```
$ lipo -info ./FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork
Architectures in the fat file: ./FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork are: i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64
```

And some said that update FBAudienceNetwork to the latest version solves the problem. So I step back to look for the solution of "framework not found".

I guess it is the problem of Xcode project settings. But is it possible caused by the framework or Unity? My Unity version is 2018.2.14f1 and my Xcode version is Version 10.1 (10B61).